# Why union Transformation is Active?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

Union Transformation is used to combine or merge multiple sources having same structure and data types. if I combine 2 sources one having 10 records and another having 10 records and the output is 20. so here input and output record is same. then why should we call Union is Active. need a example for this

Answer (score 0):

Because if you consider the path from a single source to a single target then a UNION transformation between them can/will change the number of rows

Comment: Not single source.. It's multiple sources

Comment: That's not what I said/meant. If you follow the path from any one of the sources in your mapping to any target in your mapping, and the path goes through the a UNION transformation, then the number of rows can change - therefore it is active

Comment: What is the meaning of  Is Active property in Union

Comment: number of rows input != number of  rows output